# Ruby on Rails, how to define methods that should be ued in two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have two controllers namely coordinates_controller and tweets_controller. The problem I am facing is that I have some definitions and their arguments both the controllers will be using. That is the value returned by coordinates controller will be used by tweets controller. Is there any method to sort this out?

my coordinates_controller code

```
class CoordinatesController<ApplicationController

  def paramas(b)

    @b = params[:show]
    return @b

  end
  def coor(latitude,longitude)
    @latitude=0
    @longitude=0
  end

  def search
  @a=Coordinates.where(city: params[:show]).take
    if(params[:show]== a.city) then 
      @latitude= a.latitude
      @longitude=a.longitude
    end
    if(@latitude=0 && @longitude=0) then
    return  @sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%search%' AND user_loc LIKE 'a.paramas' order by id desc"
    else if (@latitude!=0 && @longitude!=0) 
           @min_lat = @latitude - 1.0
           @max_lat = @latitude + 1.0
           @min_lng = @longitude - 1.0
           @max_lng = @longitude + 1.0
        return   @sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%search%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE 'a.paramas') ) order by id desc"
         else
        return   @sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%search%'"
         end    

    end
  end     



#  a= CoordinatesController.new
```

end
my tweets_controller.rb

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
require 'coordinates_controller.rb'
#require 'models/coordinates.rb'

  def index
#include 'coordinates_controller.rb'
    a= CoordinatesController.new
    @sql=a.search
    @tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :@page, :per_page => @per_page ).all
  end
end
```

I know this code is a total mess. I dunno how to use helper methods and modules. Can any tell me how to sort this so that I can use the some methods in more than one controller so that I can use the returned values?

I searched in Rails guides and tutorials. I also saw other tutorials but couldn't find solution. Anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, find a Rails tutorial and learn about separation between controllers and models, ActiveRecord, and a lot of other things.

Answer (score 2):

Use helper methods

put the search method in your application.helper or any other helper(Suppose you have SearchHelper

Then in your controller just add

```
include : SearchHelper
```

Comment: by doing so will the variables inside the module be available inside the tweets_controller?

Answer (score 1):

What @shiva said is correct, this seems like a job for a model rather than the controller.
If you still would like to use the controller you can create a parent controller

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
  ...
  end
end

class CoordinatesController < SearchController
  def index
     ...
     @var.search 
  end 
end

class TweetsController < SearchController
  def index
    @var.search
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

**Coordinate Model**

```
class Coordinate < ActiveRecord::Base #Or Service/Module, whatever makes more sense
  def search_coordinates_query
    # ... do your query creation here
    # ... wherever you used @a = ...
    # change it to latitude / longitude instead because you are already in an initialized object
  end
end
```

**Tweets Controllers**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    city_coordinate = Coordinate.where(:city => params[:show]).first
    @tweets = Tweet.paginate_by_sql(city_coordinate.search_coordinates_query, @page, :pre_page => @per_page).all
  end
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: is it possible to make the search definition available inside the CoordinatesController  without creating the object? or will it be okay if I create an object?

Comment: can you tell me where I will have to do it .I am not getting it fully

Comment: Should I code everything in the TweetsController? or separately? Please Help

Comment: can you help me please it says undefined method params in SearchController?

Comment: I added my answer, if you still don't get it, please find some getting started with rails and ruby tutorials to make yourself more familiar with the ecosystem of rails and the ruby language.

Answer (score 0):

Define the search method in a model and call it from any controller with parameters

you can use

> def self.method_name

to create static methods (i.e) you can call the method without creating new instance of it.

Comment: is it possible to call a method  defined  in one model in another controller? Like I have defined my search method in Coordinates model, is it possible to call it from  tweets_controller?

Comment: @user2492854 ofcourse, in your tweets_controller `c=Coordinates.new; c.search`